# Deriving curvature tensor from parallel transport

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I know that the curvature tensor $R$ of a Riemannian manifold can be derived, in a more intuitive way, by using the parallel transport. Can you give me a reference of this way to derive the curvature tensor?

Comment: What are you looking for, beyond what's at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A derivation of the curvature tensor in tensor notation.
Book : A first course in general relativity by Bernard Schutz page 157

[The curvature tensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nMZd.jpg)

Comment: Many thanks. However I found this some time ago! :-)

Answer (score -1):

On a 2D riemann manifold that lives in 3D space imagine that you have 2 vector fields on the manifold(v and u), then imagine one more vector field that directs to somewhere in the 3d space(w).Now imagine parallel transporting w along v and u vectors by order, you could do that by multiplying w with some matrices that transport w vector along the vector field(v and u). When you finish transporting you should have a vector that is in the same point with w at the start but if it is directing a different point in 3D space, difference between your first w vector and parallel transported version of it is what you will get when you use riemann curvature tensor.

Mathematical derivation comes from taking limits of v and u vectors and dividing the parallel transported version of w to vu, this makes the parallel transforming operation independent from the coordinate of the plane. So operation becomes the covariant derivative of w along u and v vectors.

Also there is a lie bracket term in riemann curvature tensor. I think it is there because it solves the problem of v and u vector fields are not intersecting at each point on the plane.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1892588)